# Nginx virtual host configuration for Drupal multisite with sub-directory

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, centos7, drupal8

We've Drupal multi-site (with different domain per site) running with single Drupal 8 code base and Nginx as web-server. Now we wanted to setup Drupal Milti-site with sub-directory for few websites in following format, and "subdirectory" should be case in-sensitive (i.e. site should be accessible with both "subdirectory" or "SubDirectory") :

1. http://site1.com (Drupal multi-site, served from "sites/site1.com")
2. http://site1.com/subdirectory (Drupal multi-site, served from "sites/site1.com.subdirectory")
3. http://site2.com (Drupal multi-site, served from "sites/site2.com")
4. http://site2.com/subdirectory (Drupal multi-site, served from "sites/site2.com.subdirectory")

We're running these websites on Nginx on CentOS. We've been able to get the sub-site working in following structure (but not with above structure) :

1. http://site1.com (Static HTML page)
2. http://site1.com/subdirectory (Drupal multi-site)

Following are nginx virtual host configuration we're using.

NOTE : I've updated nginx config to remove SSL.

```
# VHOST Config.
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site1.com;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  # Prevent files from being accessed.
  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
  location ~ /\.htaccess*$ {
    return 403;
  }
  location ~ (^|/)\. {
    return 403;
  }
  location ~ .*\.config$ {
    return 403;
  }
  location ~ /composer.*$ {
    return 403;
  }
  location ~ \..*/.*\.yml$ {
    return 403;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  location @rewrite {
    try_files $uri /subdirectory/index.php?$query_string;
  }
  location /subdirectory/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
  }

  location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
    proxy_cache_bypass 1;
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is working solution for Drupal multi-site with sub-directory.

```
# VHOST Config.
server {
  # Define server name and directory root.
  server_name site1.com;
  root /var/www/html/drupal;
  index index.php;

  # Listen to port
  listen 80;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }
  location ^~ /subdirectory {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
      # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
      # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
  }
  location @nested {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /subdirectory/index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
  }
  location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
  location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
  }
  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
    proxy_cache_bypass 1;
  }

}
```

**NOTE :**

1. Above configuration works for both "site1.com" and "site1.com/subdirectory" to server pages using Drupal 8.
2. Only issue pending is, Drupal updates doesn't work for "site1.com/subdirectory" with above config (site1.com/subdirectory/update.php works but pages after it doesn't work). For it to work, I've to make following change in vhost

   ```
     # Change try_files in 'location @nested' as below :
     location @nested {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /subdirectory/update.php?$query_string;
     }
   ```

Any help is appreciated, to fix above issue and get everything working without need to change in `location @nested`.

Hope this helps someone in need to get the Drupal 8 multi-site as sub-directory up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the things differently? My idea on what it could work for you:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site1.com;

  root /var/www/sites/site1; #I suppose that in site1 it's the code for site1.com
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
.
.
.#simple configuration here, don't care about site1.com/subdomain
.
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site2.com;

  root /var/www/sites/site2; #I suppose that in site2 it's the code for site2.com
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
.
.
.#simple configuration here, don't care about site2.com/subdomain
.
}
```

AND then , you go inside of /var/www/sites/site1 and /var/www/sites/site2 , and create a symlink to  ../site1.com.subdomain ../site2.com.subdomain like this:

```
cd  /var/www/sites/site1
ln -s ../site1.com.subdomain subdomain
cd /var/www/sites/site2
ln -s ../site2.com.subdomain subdomain
```

Like this, you have the code for each Drupal inside /var/www/sites/site1 /var/www/sites/site2 /var/www/sites/site1.com.subdomain and /var/www/sites/site2.com.subdomain

But when site1 is accessed, it'll enter /var/www/sites/site1, if site1.com/subdomain is accessed, it'll enter /var/www/sites/site1/subdomain , which following the symlink, it'll bring the connection to /var/www/sites/site1.com.subdomain.

Isn't this what you need? Or I did read wrong the question?

Comment: Drupal by default support multi site, bcoz of which I'm using same code base. I can not create different vhost bcoz for multisite with subdirectory, I need same domain, like mentioned in question.